# Graphic problems in some games, e.g., Just Cause 3: green and dark blue artifacts, textures replaced with green texture

Tags: pc, graphics-card, just-cause-3

Recently, I've started having problems with graphics in some games, e.g., *Just Cause 3*. I'm seeing green and dark blue artifacts and some textures being replaced with green textures.

No problems in these games:

> Payday 2, Just Cause 2, Metro 2033, Metro: Last Light Redux, Sniper
> Elite 3, Left 4 Dead 2

Problems in these ones:

> World of Tanks, Armored Warfare, Tomb Raider (2013), Just Cause 3

For example, here are a few screenshots from *Just Cause 3*:

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

PC specs:

- CPU: Intel Core i7 6700K
- GPU: MSI Radeon R9 390X
- RAM: 32 GB

Comment: This looks like either your GPU is dying, or it's overclocked too high.

Comment: Did you build your PC or get it custom built for you? If you built it yourself, you may want to check for damage. Also, as @Nolonar said, it may be overclocked too high.

Comment: @lewlcat I built it, but i am always very careful. When i built this PC a month ago, i noticed the GPU has coil whine, but i got rid of that by using Frame Rate Target Control in AMD Radeon Settings and set the limit to 60fps(max my monitor can show , so no point letting it render more). It was overclocked slightly before this happened, but i never overclocked over the manufacturers recommended limit.

Comment: You should check anyways, you never know. Maybe it's overheating? Otherwise I'm not really sure sorry.

Comment: @lewlcat Maximum temperature is around 75°C, but that's with the most demanding games.

Comment: In my experience (I'm no expert though... just really unlucky)... that can be caused by a number of problems from a dying gpu, to a voltage problem (read power source) or even a faulty driver. Since this happens only in a few games maybe try to see if they have some setting in common (lower everything, see how it works then get it back high on feature at the time). If activating a specific feature breaks it you can look into that and maybe find out if it is a driver issue (best case scenario). Still... my money are on dying gpu... sorry about that :(.

Comment: I would have said to try reconnecting the monitor cable, but it shouldn't show up in screenshots if that was the issue. It seems like your gpu is dying or is overclocked more than it can handle. Try defaulting to stock settings and see if the issue remains, even if it means dropping just a couple mhz.

Comment: @Chippies I reset it to default as soon as this started happening. I even tried underclocking it to see if anything changes. Oh well, I'll just RMA it.